# Change to a option on click? jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have a select inside a `<tr>`. When you click on a link I would like the select change to the option that has value "00:00".

I tried myself and came this far:

```
jQuery(this).parents('tr').find('select')
```

Comment: The English in your question is very difficult to understand. Can you rephrase or give a larger code example?

Comment: Grammar aside, it's still a poorly formulated question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this?

```
$(this).parents('tr').find('select').val('00:00');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#myLink').click(function(e){
  $(this).closest('tr').find('option').val('00:00');
  e.preventDefault();
});
```

As long as the `<select>` has an `<option ... value="00:00">...</option>`, `.val()` will locate (and select) that `<option>` for you.

[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/w2qB4/) showing how `.val()` finds the `<option>` (and selects it) for you.